# Are there any world-wide statistics about the average amount of money people hold in savings?

Tags: savings, statistics

I was surprised to learn today that [according to finder.com, the average British adult](https://www.finder.com/uk/saving-statistics) has savings of around £6,700 (unclear if it's mean or median though,) while a third of Britons have savings of less than £600. However, I also don't have context for these numbers. I'm trying to find out if there are statistics comparing the average amount of savings people hold in personal savings accounts across the world (or in regions like Europe, Asia, Africa, N/S America etc,) but couldn't find anything from a Google.

Are these stats available?

Comment: The close reason includes "off-site resources". In effect, the answer would simply be "here's the link you seek..." This is off topic.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service recommendations or other off-site resources are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly." Well granted stats become obsolete, but old stats are still useful. Is there no forum on SE for getting help in finding particular statistics?

Comment: Not that I know. Sorry.